# Special chars displaying properly on every computer

Tags: c++, special-characters

Can this code assure that Polish special chars will be properly displayed on every computer?

```
locale locpol("Polish_Poland");
locale::global(locpol);
cout.imbue(locpol);
cin.imbue(locpol);
```

On mine it works, cannot say about any other PC as I'm limited to only one.

Second thought: how can I preserve special chars during i/o operations and comparison. I've been told Windows has different char-codes for receiving and displaying chars. Is this true? How can I properly compare strings with special characters?

Do I need to *imbue* locale on... let's say - every ofstream/ifstream object I create? Like this:

```
textfile.imbue(locpol);
```

?

Comment: Actually [there are other computers](http://ideone.com/) you can try out.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The names of the locales are not standardized, so there are no guarantees across operating systems.